# Passing data between controllers with a promise Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to pass some simple boolean and string values with my promise. Here is the method renedering the a modal within the view:

```
$scope.openHjelpModal = function (field) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/produkt/ny/views/hjelpModal.html',
        controller: 'hjelpModalController',
    });


    modalInstance.result.then(function (field) {
        var kategori = '';
        var pakning = false;
        var epd = false; 
        var lansering = false; 

        switch (field) {
            case 'p':
                console.log('pakningsoppbyggning rendering');
                pakning = true; 
                epd = false; 
                lansering = false;
                kategori = 'pakningsoppbyggning'; 
                break; 
            case 'e':
                console.log('epd-kategori rendering');
                pakning = false;
                epd = true;
                lansering = false; 
                kategori = 'EPD-kategori'; 
                break; 
            case 'l':
                console.log('lansering rendereing');
                pakning = false;
                epd = false;
                lansering = true; 
                kategori = 'lansering'; 
                break; 
        }
    }, function () {
        //logService.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });

};
```

I need to pass the booleans and string to the modal somehow. I know the recomended approach would be a service, but I haven't been able to follow any of the solutions provided here so far.

Here is how I will be using the variables in the modal(html file):

```
<h4>Hjelp for:  {{kategori}} </h4>

<div ng-if="lansering">
    <p> kommer fra lansering</p>
</div>

<div ng-if="epd">
    <p> kommer fra epd</p>
</div>

<div ng-if="pakning">
    <p> kommer fra pakning</p>
</div>




<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-green pull-left" type="button" ng-click="lukk();">Lukk</button>
</div>
```

running console log from the hjelpModalController returns undefined, this is with the changes provided in the answers:

```
     $scope.openHjelpModal = function (field) {

                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    templateUrl: 'app/produkt/ny/views/hjelpModal.html',
                    controller: 'hjelpModalController',
                    resolve: function () {
                            return field; 
                    }
                });
                console.log(field); // works here

    }
```

And from the hjelpModalController:

```
angular.module('app').controller('hjelpModalController', hjelpModalController); 
hjelpModalController.$inject = ['$scope','$uibModalInstance'];

function hjelpModalController($scope, $uibModalInstance, field) {
    console.log(field); // returns undefined

}
```

UPDATE:

Here is the latest progress i have made:

controller passing the variable:

```
   $scope.openHjelpModal = function (field) {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'app/produkt/ny/views/hjelpModal.html',
                controller: 'hjelpModalController',
                resolve: {
                    selectedHelpModal: function () {
                        console.log(field); // correct output
                        return field; 
                    }
                }
            });



            modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                console.log('or here'); 
                console.log(field); // correct output 
            });
}
```

controller recieving the variable:

```
    angular.module('app').controller('hjelpModalController', hjelpModalController); 

    hjelpModalController.$inject = ['$scope','$uibModalInstance']; 

    function hjelpModalController($scope, $uibModalInstance, field) {
        console.log('hjelp modal controler is running'); 
        console.log(field); // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `uibModal` provides a `resolve` param for this purpose.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/produkt/ny/views/hjelpModal.html',
    controller: 'hjelpModalController',
    resolve: {
        field: function() {
            return field;
        }
    }
});
```

It is then accessible by DI inside your modal controller (the DI name follows the key name in resolve)

```
.controller('hjelpModalController', function(field) {
    console.log(field); 
})
```

Comment: running your solution returns the following console output: Uncaught SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or inside a block.

Comment: @Steingrrim sorry, resolve should be an object instead of function

Comment: With some minor changes, your answer solved my problem. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a small change in the code provided above.

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'app/produkt/ny/views/hjelpModal.html',
    controller: 'hjelpModalController',
    animation: true,
    resolve: {
        field: function() {
            return field;
        }
    }
});
```

And in the modal controller:

```
.controller('hjelpModalController', function(field) {
    console.log(field); 
})
```

If you want to dismiss the modal (most probably you will) add `$uibModalInstance` as a param into the modal controller.

```
controller('hjelpModalController', function(field,$uibModalInstance) {
    console.log(field); 
  $scope.cancel = function() {
  $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};



})
```